# Node.js exported module file - variable keeps getting updated after using splice on a different variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, variables

I'm kinda new to node.js and was trying to create a card game, which would be multiplayer. here is the issue. I have 2 files:

mainCardSelector.js
app.js

Now essentially I have a function called startGame which will use a method from "mainCardSelector.js" to randomly draw a card from my deck of cards stored in an object "roomCards". Now once the card is drawn I run a splice command to look for the correct room and then take out the card drawn from the deck for that specific room. Now the issue is that while the card does get removed, the next time the cards get assigned into a room, the previously deleted card from the deck is missing from the fresh deck of cards. Here is a bit of code to put it into perspective.

"MainCardSelector.js"

```
//Storage for all cards
const cards = ['2C', '2D', '2H', '2S', '3C', '3D', '3H', '3S',
'4C', '4D', '4H', '4S', '5C', '5D', '5H', '5S',
'6C', '6D', '6H', '6S', '7C', '7D', '7H', '7S',
'8C', '8D', '8H', '8S', '9C', '9D', '9H', '9S',
'10C', '10D', '10H', '10S',
'AC', 'AD', 'AH', 'AS',
'JC', 'JD', 'JH', 'JS',
'KC', 'KD', 'KH', 'KS',
'QC', 'QD', 'QH', 'QS',
];

function selectMainCard(){
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    let mainCard     = cards[randomNumber];
    return mainCard;
}

module.exports.selectMainCard =  selectMainCard;
```

"app.js"

```
roomCards = []
 startGame(_socket, data){
                //Session vars for various rooms
                const mainCard          = mainCardSelector.selectMainCard();
                const deckCards         = mainCardSelector.deckCards;
     
                roomCards.push({roomId:data.roomId, cards:deckCards});
                console.log('Distributed cards **** ' + deckCards.length);
                //Starting the game 
                console.log("game has been started by " + data.username);
                //Removing the card that got used
                 const sessionCards = roomCards.indexOf(roomCards.find(x => parseInt(x.roomId) === parseInt(data.roomId)));
                 console.log("Session array id : ", sessionCards)
                 const excludedCard = roomCards[sessionCards].cards.indexOf(mainCard);
                 roomCards[sessionCards].cards.splice(excludedCard,1);
                 console.log(roomCards[sessionCards].cards);
                 console.log(roomCards[sessionCards].cards.length);
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Have an amazing day :))

Comment: copy the cards, work and splice from the copy, then on new game reset the copy

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the response. But what baffles me is that I never actually splice cards from the original deckCards variable which contains all 52 cards. I only deduct the cards from the specific room which is stored in roomCards array. So why does it change is the question